# Populating ListView from a SQLite DB not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to populate a ListView using data from a pre-loaded SQLite DB. I'm not getting any errors, but no data is appearing in the list view either and I'm not certain why.

I've honestly read everything I can, between the 10-12 various threads here on the same thing, to youtube videos, to tutorials. I suspect I'm on the right track, but I'm not sure exactly what I've missed.

How I'm populating the ListView:

```
    // Populate the ListView
    ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.row_item,R.id.bonusListCode,theList);
    Cursor data = appDBHelper.getAppDataListContents();
    if (data.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "There are no contents in this list!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        for(int i=0;i<data.getCount();i++) {
            data.moveToPosition(i);
            theList.add(data.getString(0));
        }
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
```

I made an adapter, but I don't call it anywhere, and I'm not entirely sure 1) How to properly call it; 2) If it is the way I'm supposed to do this.

appDataDBAdapter:

```
    public class AppDataDBAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    public AppDataDBAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    // The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it,
    // you don't bind any data to the view at this point.
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
    }

    // The bindView method is used to bind all data to a given view
    // such as setting the text on a TextView.
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Find fields to populate in inflated template
        TextView bonusCode = view.findViewById(R.id.bonusListCode);
        TextView bonusName = view.findViewById(R.id.bonusListName);
        TextView bonusCity = view.findViewById(R.id.bonusListCity);
        TextView bonusState = view.findViewById(R.id.bonusListState);
        TextView bonusCategory = view.findViewById(R.id.bonusListCategory);

        // Extract properties from cursor
        String sCode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("sCode"));
        String sName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("sName"));
        String sCity = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("sCity"));
        String sState = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("sState"));
        String sCategory = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("sCategory"));

        // Populate fields with extracted properties
        bonusCode.setText(sCode);
        bonusName.setText(sName);
        bonusCity.setText(sCity);
        bonusState.setText(sState);
        bonusCategory.setText(sCategory);
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you simply use `SimpleCursorAdapter`? all you have to do is to pass your `Cursor` to `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor, thats all

Comment: I added the adapter I made to my original question. It is an extension to Cursor, so not sure if that is the same as `SimpleCursorAdapter` or not.

Comment: you can extend `CursorAdapter` (or `ResourceCursorAdapter`) but honestly `SimpleCursorAdapter` is good enough in your case

Comment: compare it to the answer below `listView.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_item, data, new String[] {"sCode", "sName"}, new int[] {R.id.bonusListCode, R.id.bonusListName}, 0));` - yes, thats all

Comment: @pskink ok, that makes so much more sense now that I have seen it in action. Thank you so much. Since this is pulling the Cursor, which is based on my DBHelper, do I even need the DBAdapter I made above? I believe this SimpleCursorAdapter is taking the place of the one I wrote, correct?

Comment: you mean `AppDataDBAdapter`? no, you dont need it: `SimpleCursorAdapter` does the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//populate an ArrayList<String> from the database and then view it
 ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);
    ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = appDBHelper.getAppDataListContents();
    if (data.getCount() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "There are no contents in this list!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        for(int i=0;i<data.count;i++) {
            data.moveToPosition(i);
            theList.add(data.getString(1));
          }
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
```